# Why is my excel vba code throwing error when the count of rows for a particular data increases 16?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, vba6

I have a vba tool which analyzes the excel data and counts the number of data for a particular person and prepares powerpoint reports by pasting the comments for each person based on it. I have noticed, the tool throws error when the data count (rows) for a person increases 16. The error says- "integer is out of range. 18 is not in the valid range of 1 to 17" . Below is the code:

Note- I am a beginner

' Update Comments Slide

```
Set Sl = PPres.Slides(4)
Set sh = Sl.Shapes("TextBox 7")
strText = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
strText = Replace(strText, "____", strFirst)
sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = strText

Set sh = Sl.Shapes("Table Placeholder 3")
For s = 1 To aA
  sh.Table.Rows(s + 1).Cells(1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(clsCommA.Item(s))
Next
If aA < 16 Then
    For s = 16 To aA + 1 Step -1
        sh.Table.Rows(s + 1).Delete
    Next
End If
Set clsCommA = Nothing
```

Comment: Can you include the line of code that begins `aA = ...`?

Comment: Upon which line is the error being thrown?

Comment: What I notice is you have your if statement (If aA < 16 only around the first for loop? Maybe a good time to debug your code? Most likely aA is bigger than the rows in the table.

Comment: Search the VBA code for "is not in the valid range of" and look at what that code is checking.